# Problems finding terms in multiple .gz files recursively

Tags: syntax, grep, zcat, gnu-findutils

We have various archive files in a folder, and I'm trying to recursively search through these for a particular string. I've found lots of examples of various ways to do this, but I've not been successful. This is from my latest iteration:

```
find . -name "*.gz" -print -exec zcat {} | grep -a -i "NTDS"
```

With the above, I'm getting "find: missing argument to -exec". Can someone point out what I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: You're missing a `\;` after `{}`.

Comment: You might also be interested in `zgrep` which is actually the combination of your `zcat` and `grep`